# Possible repeated conjugacy classes in Thompson's Rigidity Criterion

Tags: galois-theory

In Volklein's $\textit{Groups as Galois Groups}$, the rigidity criterion is given as:

$\textbf{Definition 2.15}$ Let $(C_1, \dots, Cr)$ be a tuple of conjugacy classes in a group $G$. We say it is $\textbf{rigid}$ in $G$ if the following hold:

(a) There exist generators $g_1, \dots, g_r$ of $G$ with $g_1 \cdot \dots \cdot g_r = 1$ and $g_i \in C_i$ for $i = 1, \dots, r$.

(b) If ${g'}_1, \dots, {g'}_r$ is another system of generators of G with the same properties, then there exists a unique element $g \in G$ with $gg_ig^{-1} = {g'}_i$

My question is this: do the conjugacy classes need to be distinct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they do not have to be.

Reference: (Page 104) Representations and Characters of Finite Groups
By M. J. Collins.

Comment: Very definitive, @AlwaysNeedHelp.  Can you think of an example of a Galois realization over the rationals that relies on rigidity and uses a class vector with a repeated class?